# How do I replicate a chain lift?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In Minecraft, I am creating a roller coaster. I want to replicate a chain lift for the beginning, but I do not know how. Is there a way to create one (or something similar)?

For those who do not know what a chain lift is, it is the beginning segment of most roller coasters, where the car is pulled up by a chain.

Example of a chain lift:

Comment: Why not just use a powered rail?

Comment: When I use powered rails, it launches the coaster too fast up the "hill,' ruining the experience (imo).

Comment: So use a series of powered rails, separated by unpowered ones. Unless you're saying the initial boost from a powered rail is too strong.

Comment: Went to go test it myself, and using the powered then some normal ones sequence, it is either too fast (zooming up the hill) or it is jittery (speeds up then slows down, then speeds up, etc).

Comment: Are you open to command block solutions, or is this on survival?

Comment: It is on creative, so I am open to anything.

Comment: Just a question to anyone trying to make an answer, could there be a piston way to do it?

Comment: piston elevator?

Comment: I was thinking using pistons to push it up then over at a tempo that I desire, until the top.

Comment: Pistons.. will be very large, slow, and loud. Also it will be awkward in movement anyways.

Answer (score 1):

#### Power the golden rail with rapid pulser

Video:

[image]

Comment: Does this work uphill? Because if the cart ever stops on the way, it will reverse.

Comment: @MrLemon Yes. But preventing them from changing direction while going is another problem..